# Preview for lightning screen flow component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

When you create a custom lightning flow component is there a way to provide a preview too so I don't get the message "No preview is available for this component" and it doesn't like this example but looks like it will look on the screen when the flow runs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time (as of Summer 22 release)